# Hyperledger Besu for creating accounts

Tags: blockchain, besu, hyperledger

I am able to setup hyperledger besu for creating private ethereum network(followed the official documents with 3 testing accounts in gnesis file) and able to connect to metamask as well. But its not showing any accounts. I am getting null when doing eth.accounts().

As per the documentation, you can create accounts in Hyperledger besu using 3rd party tools ethsigner and Metamask.I created account using metamask but its not getting reflected in eth.accounts().

Answer (score 0):

[Besu, for security reasons, doesn't include account management.](https://besu.hyperledger.org/en/stable/public-networks/how-to/send-transactions/#use-wallets-for-key-management)
You have to use an external tool line EthSigner that will allow this using vaults or other secure storage for your account key.